# Getting all the combination of numbers from a list that would sum to a specific number

Tags: r

I have the following `list` of numbers (`1,3,4,5,7,9,10,12,15`) and I want to find out all the possible combinations of `3` numbers from this `list` that would sum to `20`.

My research on `stackoverflow` has led me to this post:
[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum?noredirect=1&lq=1)

There is a solution provided by Mark which stand as follows:

```
subset_sum = function(numbers,target,partial=0){
if(any(is.na(partial))) return()
s = sum(partial)
if(s == target)  print(sprintf("sum(%s)=%s",paste(partial[-1],collapse="+"),target))
if(s > target) return()
for( i in seq_along(numbers)){
n = numbers[i]
remaining = numbers[(i+1):length(numbers)]
subset_sum(remaining,target,c(partial,n))
}
}
```

However I am having a hard time trying to tweak this set of codes to match my problem. Or may be there is a simpler solution?

I want the output in `R` to show me the list of numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combn` function and filter to meet your criteria. I have performed below calculation in 2 steps but one can perform it in single step too.

```
v <-  c(1,3,4,5,7,9,10,12,15)
AllComb <- combn(v, 3)   #generates all combination taking 3 at a time.
PossibleComb  <- AllComb[,colSums(AllComb) == 20]  #filter those with sum == 20

#Result: 6 sets of 3 numbers (column-wise) 
PossibleComb
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    3    3    4
# [2,]    4    7    9    5    7    7
# [3,]   15   12   10   12   10    9
# 

# Result in list
split(PossibleComb, col(PossibleComb))

# $`1`
# [1]  1  4 15
# 
# $`2`
# [1]  1  7 12
# 
# $`3`
# [1]  1  9 10
# 
# $`4`
# [1]  3  5 12
# 
# $`5`
# [1]  3  7 10
# 
# $`6`
# [1] 4 7 9
```

Answer (score 1):

The `combn` also have a `FUN` parameter which we can describe to output as `list` and then `Filter` the `list` elements based on the condition

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x) == 20, combn(v, 3, FUN = list))
#[[1]]
#[1]  1  4 15

#[[2]]
#[1]  1  7 12

#[[3]]
#[1]  1  9 10

#[[4]]
#[1]  3  5 12

#[[5]]
#[1]  3  7 10

#[[6]]
#[1] 4 7 9
```

#### data

```
v <-  c(1,3,4,5,7,9,10,12,15)
```